# Run only one test on CircleCI (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rake, circleci

Sometimes I have a broken test on CircleCI, where the error can't be replicated locally. Instead of waiting for the whole suite to run, I'd like to run that one test individually. (I know I can ssh in, but that's time-consuming and running it that way wouldn't exactly replicate the usual automated test sequence.)

My aim is to make a temporary config commit to run just one test (ideally just a test method, but the whole class would be fine too). I can think of two possible solutions: (A) edit app.rake to make the default rake task run a single test; or (B) edit circle.yml to run just the one test from command-line using `rake test`. Any clue on either of these?